# I have arranged to discuss "to buy" his house

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

When we have three verbs in the same clause. And we need to decide whether use "ing" or "to" with the third one.

Should we choose based on the main verb  (first one) or the second verb?

In the following example, *arrange* should follow with "to + infinitive" verb and *discuss*  should follow by "ing" very. so should we use "to buy" or "buying"?

> I have arranged to discuss **to buy** his house.
>
> I have arranged to discuss **buying** his house.

Another example:

> I never considered offering **buying** his car.
>
> I never considered offering **to buy** his car.

Comment: I may be widely off base but I'm pretty sure you can't use "to ___" twice in a row.

Comment: @Catija I want to try to persuade you to change your opinion.

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, thanks... So then why is it wrong here? Because it certainly *is*... It's something I just *know* is wrong but not why it is so... just like I know that "offering to buy" is correct and the other is wrong...

Comment: @Catija See my answer, forthcoming presently.

Comment: @StoneyB Is it going to be written such that a dumb native speaker can understand? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With these *catenative* constructions, each verb 'selects' the form of its complement without regard to earlier verbs in the chain.

*Discuss* selects gerund-participle complements but not infinitival complements, and *arranged* selects infinitival complements but not gerund-participle complements; so you have to say:

> <sup>ok</sup>I have arranged to discuss buying his house.
>   <sup>∗</sup> I have arranged discussing buying his house.
>   <sup>∗</sup> I have arranged to discuss to buy his house.

Similarly, *consider* selects gerund-participle complements but not infinitival complements, and *offer* selects infinitival complements but not gerund-participle complements; so you have to say:

> <sup>ok</sup>I have never considered offering to buy his car.
>   <sup>∗</sup>  I have never considered offering buying his car.
>   <sup>∗</sup>  I have never considered to offer to buy his car.

Note however that *offer* may take as **object** an 'uncontrolled' gerund-participle clause—a clause whose subject is not inferred from the head clause.

> He offered *buying a car* as an alternative to taking the bus.

Comment: This is really the first time I hear of "select". Is it equal to another term "license"?

Comment: @user178049 Yes, it is. And there's a third term, "subcategorize". They're all pretty much the same thing.

Comment: There seems to be a peculiarity of the verb 'arrange'. In addition to 'arrange to do sth', we also have 'arrange *for sb* to do sth'. However, 'for' is not usually needed in catenative constructions like 'ask sb to do sth', 'suggest sb doing sth', 'expect sb to do sth', etc. Is it also a kind of license through which 'for sb' functions as Prepositional Phrase Complement, or just part of the non-finite clause Complement?

Comment: @KinzleB Usually these *for .. to* complements occur with verbs which also use *for NP* complements. *Arrange* is one of these: we say "Arrange for a replacement, for a car" &c. Similarly, *Ask* takes *for* complements--"She asked for help, for a job, for her brother"--and also takes *for .. to* clausal complements--"She asked for him to be appointed" as well as "She asked them to appoint him".There's a sort of merger of *for* functions here. I don't think it matters how you parse it.

Answer (score 1):

> I have arranged to discuss to buy his house.

makes for awkward reading, and questionable grammar. "To discuss to buy" is difficult reading

> I have arranged to discuss buying his house.

reads much better, and is grammatically alright.

> I have arranged discussion on buying this house.

is another option. It leaves out one of the verbs.

> I never considered offering buying his car.

reads very badly in English. Do not consider this. The two "ing" forms back to back make for difficult understanding .

> I never considered offering to buy his car.

is good.
In both examples offered, "I have arranged", and "I never considered" the issue was in the second and third verbs. You resolved the issue (the same word construction back to back)  with the second version in both cases.